# EF migration dropped the "dbo." prefix, is that OK?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

After some time away from a project, I recently added a new db migration (`Add-Migration`) and the generated code looks like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.OrigName", newName: "NewName");
    }
```

i.e. the "dbo." prefix is gone. Will that cause issues or is fine?

Comment: Try running it and see? It's not a problem, because `dbo` is the default schema anyway.

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine, however, I am not a db expert and maybe there are other consequences to consider. Or maybe there aren't as you suggest. Just wanted to make sure because from a layman point of view, it seems weird that the schema is "changing" (maybe not really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that this particular implementation restriction (no schema on `newName`) is a leaky abstraction.

According to the documentation for MS SQL's [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) stored procedure:

> ***newName* must be a one-part name** and must follow the rules for identifiers.

`sp_rename` is almost certainly unable to move objects between schemas.  [`ALTER SCHEMA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx) is used for that.

Comment: So in laymen terms, will it cause problems or not? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using MS SQL: No.  It won't, and it can't, because `RenameTable` wraps `sp_rename`.  Other providers may behave differently.